# How do I call a method from another view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I want to call this method:

```
- (void)getUserFriendTargetDialogRequest {
    currentAPICall = kAPIFriendsForTargetDialogRequests;
    [self apiGraphFriends];
}
```

from this conditional statement that's in another viewcontroller:

```
if (idx == 2) {
        NSLog(@"you touched menu 2");

        APICallsViewController *apiViewController = [APICallsViewController alloc];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:apiViewController animated:YES]; 
    }
```

can anyone help with the syntax on this?

thanks so much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you probably also want to init your APICallsViewController via:

```
    APICallsViewController *apiViewController = [[APICallsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Then if that getUserFriend... is a method of APIViewController, you can do this:

```
    [apiViewController getUserFriendTargetDialogRequest];
```

However, since you aren't passing any arguments in from your other view controller, you might consider calling it in the init method, or the viewDidLoad method of APICallsViewController.

Answer (score 5):

```
OtherViewController *viewController = [[OtherViewController alloc]         
                                           init];
[viewController methodName];
[viewController release];
```

Answer (score 4):

1>Just alloc the class in which the method is and then call it through object of that class.

```
ViewControllWithMethod *view=[ViewControllWithMethod  alloc]]init];
[view getUserFriendTargetDialogRequest];
```

2>Instead of instance method you can make it as class method then you will be able to call it through `className.getUserFriendTargetDialogRequest`